# how should I handle this into-the-wall section of the refrigerant pipe insulation?

Tags: hvac, insulation, pipe, outdoor

[image: refrigerant pipe insulation into the wall section]

I had my first insulation replacement. The section that went into the wall was such a tight space; I didn't believe I could wrap my new insulation around it. How was the old insulation so much thinner? I left that old insulation in there and used electrical tape to join the old with the new. It felt incomplete. Any recommendations? or just leave it alone?

On a side note, my tape wrapping skill is level 0. I found it hard in that space to have a clean smooth wrap. I'm thinking to use a duct tape (one wide piece) to cover the imperfection. :D

Comment: Don't let your OCD kill you! If you're worried about that one little ridge at the top or the 3 little wrinkles at the bottom, trust me - this is better than 95% of the rest of the world would do it and nobody, but _nobody_ will ever see a flaw here. There are more important things to waste mental energy "worrying" about. Those wrinkles are _not_ fatal flaws to this tape wrap job.

Comment: hahah...You are right. That's totally OCD. Thank you for calling out on me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have sheets of neoprene insulation as thin as 1/8” all you need to do in reality is prevent condensation even spray foam in the hole allowing it to encapsulate the lines will be enough.
Don’t worry about your tape skills you are really just preventing uv exposure as this breaks down the insulation.
Tape also seals from air movement again helping to prevent condensation.
You are ahead of some DYI by asking,,, good job.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the OCD in me makes me wanting to get a UV shielding jacket for the insulation. :p  I guess it is a good thing I can't find it in my local hardware store.

Comment: The tape will do the job no other shield is really needed.